# strange g++ linking behavior depending on arguments order

Tags: reference, g++, undefined, msys

I was trying to compile a simple opengl program on msys using g++. To my surprise the linker was complaining on undefined references:

```
$ g++ -mwindows -lopengl32 glut_md2.cpp
C:\Users\...\cceQtYAy.o:glut_md2.cpp:(.text+0x67a): undefined reference to `glGenTextures@8'
C:\Users\...\cceQtYAy.o:glut_md2.cpp:(.text+0x696): undefined reference to `glBindTexture@8'
....
```

After googling for a while I found that the problem was in g++ arguments order:

```
$ g++ glut_md2.cpp -mwindows -lopengl32
--- all ok! ---
```

The interesting thing is that the correct argument orders in g++ is in the first example. That is:

```
$ g++ --help
Usage: g++.exe [options] file...
....
```

Am I missing something? Why moving options *after* the file argument makes a compilation success? I never had this issue when compiling natively on linux...

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into this problem once or twice, you should put -L and -l at the end of command line. g++ doesn't link, it invokes ld and pass arguments, ld man:

> The linker will search an archive only once, at the location where it
> is specified on the command line.  If the archive defines a symbol
> which was undefined in some object which appeared before the archive
> on the command line, the linker will include the appropriate file(s)
> from the archive.  However, an undefined symbol in an object appearing
> later on the command line will not cause the linker to search the
> archive again.
>
> ld -o  /lib/crt0.o hello.o -lc

Comment: Strange. I think g++ should pass linking options to the linker either way cause it's very explicit in the above example. Voodoo magic...