# C++11 thread error runtime

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Hello I have problem with threads in C++11. I have ubuntu 64bit 13.10(testing) with g++ 4.8.1.
I tried to compile code:

```
#include <thread>

void func()
{
   // do some work
}

int main()
{
   std::thread t(func);
   t.join();
   return 0;
}
```

with options: -std=c++11 -pthread -lpthread. Compilation was successful, but when I tried to run it, I've received an error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
>   what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not
>   permitted

Comment: Could you try with -pthread -std=c++11 ? (without -lpthread)

Comment: Seems that other people have this issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1228201

Answer (score 6):

I think the other answers are a bit misleading. What is important is that you only need `-pthread`. The order of *this* flag is *not* important!

`-pthread` will automatically link with `libpthread` and it'll do so correctly. Note that you need to provide this option both **when compiling *and* linking** your code (except when you do everything at once, of course).

Only when you provide `-lpthread` explicitly, the order of where you put might be important, but as already mentioned, you shouldn't add it explicitly when using `-pthread`.

Comment: Using `-pthread` is not going to help in this case. I have the same environment, and the only solution is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19359353/476681)

Answer (score 5):

You probably have the same problem as mentioned here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1228201

Add this flag to your command line. It will force g++ to link with the given libraries.

```
-Wl,--no-as-needed
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that order matters, or atleast, that's what is said in this thread:
[C++ Threads, std::system_error - operation not permitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274032/c-threads-stdsystem-error-operation-not-permitted)

Comment: Correct. And I never knew why _exactly_, but this one explains it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827938/strange-g-linking-behavior-depending-on-arguments-order Basically, if you use `-lwhatever` _before_ the file that needs the library, the linker discards it since it didn't see any of the symbols used so far.

Comment: yes linked libraries must be on the right of the file that needs it. But is it really the problem of the OP ? Seems that other people have the same issue on Ubuntu 13.10.