# gcc link error depending on the input file argument position

Tags: gcc, linker

- Environment
  $ lsb_release -a
  Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
  $gcc --version
  gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
- Problem

  - link error happens depending on the position of input file.
  - NG
    $gcc -lsndfile  -o snd-003 snd-003.c

  > ```
  >     /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccMmdgxh.o: in function `main':  
  >     snd-003.c:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `sf_open'  
  >     /usr/bin/ld: snd-003.c:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `sf_readf_short'  
  >     /usr/bin/ld: snd-003.c:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to `sf_close'  
  >     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  > ```

  - OK
    If you change the argument position of input file, then link error does not happen.
    $gcc snd-003.c -lsndfile  -o snd-003
- Other info

  - snd-003.c is uploaded below (just FYI).
    https://file.io/PA4K22CzXwsi
  - this problem happens on other gcc version

    - gcc 8.4.0
    - gcc 7.5.0
  - this error happens on other libraries too (e.x. libssl).
  - there is no this problem on other machines.

    - deiban 10.9 (gcc 8.3.0)
    - debian 8.3 (gcc 4.9.2)
  - similar problem reported long time ago, but it's not solved.
    [strange g++ linking behavior depending on arguments order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827938/strange-g-linking-behavior-depending-on-arguments-order)
- Question
  Does anyone have some clue on what's wrong with this ? gcc ? environment ?
  I want to know the root cause of this behavior.
  Any comments are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the expected behavior (https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html):

> The linker will search an archive only once, at the location where it is specified on the command line. If the archive defines a symbol which was undefined in some object which appeared before the archive on the command line, the linker will include the appropriate file(s) from the archive. However, an undefined symbol in an object appearing later on the command line will not cause the linker to search the archive again. See the -( option for a way to force the linker to search archives multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It answers my question half. 
But, I'm wondering why NG command works on other platform, and what makes this difference ... linker behavior is changed at some point ??

Comment: Is it exactly the same source code, with the same gcc command, that works on other platforms ? It can indeed be related to dynamic vs static linking  depending on the environment.

Comment: > Is it exactly the same source code, with the same gcc command, that works on other platforms ? 
Yes. it's exactly the same source code, same gcc command. 
the difference is only the gcc version and the platform as explained in "other info" section. But I do not think gcc version does affect this behavior difference.
So, wondering what's affect this behavior difference..